# Car stuck in GTA 5 first mission

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

So guys there you go, just started playing GTA V and my car gets stuck in the garage. Its around the 27:00 - 27:03 part in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y-3SYvnNxC8), and my car gets stuck. I can move my camera around, but cant exit the car and it doesn't change the scene. Using PS3 (super slim). Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try restarting the mission?

Comment: it takes forever to open the "menu", so I exited the game and played the mission again. no difference

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a glitch in the game.

Driving the car into the garage should trigger the cutscene & the continuation of the story. Try restating the mission or restarting the game itself. Similarly, check for updates as this bug may have been fixed in a patch.

Alternatively, if you kill your character three times during a mission you'll have the option to skip that section of the mission. Use explosives, fire, police, or large falls to  kill yourself three times and you'll be able to skip directly to the cutscene and the end of the mission.